# I keep getting "true" statement for the first match of email and the rest all are "False"

Tags: vb.net, validation, email-validation

I am currently doing a program that will detect Email in a text file, i am able to bring out the email, but couldnt validate the email. The validation code is something look like this:

```
    Dim truelist As New ArrayList
    For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
           truelist.Add(ListBox2.Items(i))
    Next
    For Each item In truelist
        Dim result As Boolean
        Dim rgx As New Regex("^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)(.[a-z]{2,4})$")

        If rgx.IsMatch(item) Then
            MessageBox.Show(item, "true")
            result = True

        Else
            MessageBox.Show(item, "false")
            result = False

        End If
    Next
```

and my sample input is :

1. ys_host@hotmail.com
2. .kjdsd.@hotmail.com
3. .as.das.@hotmail.com
4. ~!U#)(!#U@hotmail.com
5. idgohwoijgw12942149!@hotmail.com
6. ys_host@hotmail.com

Even though my 1st input the same with last input, but i will get false return from the last input

Comment: Can you also add some sample input data, please? Otherwise we will never be able to guess what data is causing  your problem.

Comment: @JayV i have updated my input, thank you for your advise

Comment: Can't reproduce. The only valid matches are the first and the last and those are both validated.

Comment: Have you trimmed your inputs to ensure no leading or trailing spaces? `Trim(ListBox2.Items(i))`

Comment: @AJD Thanks! its actually worked! thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex does not account for any space, and evaluates the characters from the start of the input (`^`) to the end (`$`). As such, any leading or trailing spaces in the input strings would fail to be matched.

`Trim()` is the VB command that removes spaces at the end or beginning of strings. `LTrim` and `RTrim` are specific commands that remove spaces at either end. Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.trim(v=vs.110).aspx; while https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/trimming indicates that `String.Trim()` works on whitespaces in general.

You could `Trim()` the inputs to your `ListBox` and this should solve the problem. The safer and better way in this context is to `Trim()` the inputs to the Regex - data validation at the most effective time in the code. The sample code (based on your code) would be:

```
Dim truelist As New ArrayList
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
       truelist.Add(Trim(ListBox2.Items(i))) '*** Changed this line, added "Trim"
Next
For Each item In truelist
    Dim result As Boolean
    Dim rgx As New Regex("^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)(.[a-z]{2,4})$")
    If rgx.IsMatch(item) Then
        MessageBox.Show(item, "true")
        result = True
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(item, "false")
        result = False
    End If
Next
```

The alternative syntax is `truelist.Add(ListBox2.Items(i).Trim())`.

As an aside, this code is ripe for setting up in a function - enabling re-use. Here is an example of the refactoring:

```
'[Main function elements ... Include Sub/Function header etc.]
Dim truelist As New ArrayList
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
       truelist.Add(Trim(ListBox2.Items(i))) '*** Changed this line, added "Trim"
Next
For Each item In truelist
    Dim result As Boolean
    If IsValidEmailAddress(item) Then
        ' Do valid stuff
    Else
        ' Do not-valid stuff
    End If
Next

'[Main Sub/Function tail, include End Sub/Function as relevant]

Function IsValidEmailAddress(value as String) as Boolean
    Dim rgx As New Regex("^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)(.[a-z]{2,4})$")
    return rgx.IsMatch(item.Trim()) ' Note use of Trim here for encapsulated data validation.
    ' encapsulated data validation may or may not be what you want.
End Function
```